# Create a dictionary from an array with multiple values assigned to a single key

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I create a dictionary from a multidimensional array of dimension (x,y), using the raw ID as key and part of the column as values?

I would like, given a key, to receive as separate values the first (y - t) column as an array and the last `t` as a second array.

Exemple:

If this is the first row of the (x,y) array:

```
array =[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

I would like to receive, given the key: `ID = 0`, the following values related to that key ( `array([a,b,c,d,e]), [f], [g]` ).

In order to store different parts of the same array separately under the same ID so that if one operates on a single part and, for example, shuffles the rows of the matrix, one could always trace back the other parts of the array using the ID.

Comment: What do you mean by "raw ID"? Can you give an example input and output? What does "the first raw" mean?

Comment: Yes Id is the matrix row index, what I mean is that each row is identified by a decimal number called id. The desired output given an ID (key) would it be three separate arrays, one containing five elements, two containing just one